# Grasping the concept behind a certain javascript functionality

Tags: javascript

I found this script on the Internet, and i would like very much to understand it.I know i may get negative votes, but i really would like some prospect about the way this functionality works in estimating the current world population, especially with the values chosen in the scripts and the reason behind each of these values. I'd appreciate any help please.

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function maind() {
            startdate = new Date()
            now(startdate.getYear(), startdate.getMonth(), startdate.getDate(), startdate.getHours(), startdate.getMinutes(), startdate.getSeconds())
        }

        function ChangeValue(number, pv) {
            numberstring = ""
            var j = 0
            var i = 0
            while (number > 1) {

                numberstring = (Math.round(number - 0.5) % 10) + numberstring
                number = number / 10
                j++
                if (number > 1 && j == 3) {
                    numberstring = "," + numberstring
                    j = 0
                }
                i++
            }

            numberstring = numberstring

            if (pv == 1) {
                document.getElementById("worldpop").innerHTML = numberstring
            }
        }

        function now(year, month, date, hours, minutes, seconds) {
            startdatum = new Date(year, month, date, hours, minutes, seconds)

            var now = 5600000000.0
            var now2 = 5690000000.0
            var groeipercentage = (now2 - now) / now * 100
            var groeiperseconde = (now * (groeipercentage / 100)) / 365.0 / 24.0 / 60.0 / 60.0
            nu = new Date()
            schuldstartdatum = new Date(96, 1, 1)
            secondenoppagina = (nu.getTime() - startdatum.getTime()) / 1000
            totaleschuld = (nu.getTime() - schuldstartdatum.getTime()) / 1000 * groeiperseconde + now
            ChangeValue(totaleschuld, 1);


            timerID = setTimeout("now(startdatum.getYear(),startdatum.getMonth(),startdatum.getDate(),startdatum.getHours(),startdatum.getMinutes(),startdatum.getSeconds())", 200)
        }

        window.onload = maind
    </script>

    Current world population (estimated): <span id="worldpop" style="font-weight: bold"></span>.
</body>
```

Comment: This is a chunk of poorly written javascript. What exactly don't you understand about it?

Comment: @georg the chosen static values in it, such as the dates and var now, var now2 ... And if you can suggest a better existing script that you're aware of, i'd much appreciate it .

Comment: The script essentially says "On the first of January 1996 there were 5,600,000,000 people with an expected growth of 90,000,000 per year. Calculate the growth per second out of it and show the approx. value for the world population every 200 ms"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code says something like that:
The world population on Jan 1st, 1996 was 5600000000.
Next year, presumably, Jan 1st, 1997, it was 5690000000.
Based on that data the code tries to extrapolate population growth till present time, assuming `5690000000 - 5600000000` as a yearly population increment.